# script to send e-mail for success or failure

Tags: shell-script

My Oracle backup sends out an e-mail with notification that backup completed and it was successful or failed depending upon it find some pattern. Our backup logs are getting very big - 14mg. Since this file is larger then 10MB, this messages are getting dropped by the Exchange servers.

Please help me fix this issue, i.e. i need this process to just send an e-mail with the pattern "ORA-" or "RMAN-" error codes(if failure) or just a e-mail that indicates success or failure.

NOTE: this is just a part of the code - Let me know if you have any questions.

```
#### Check for RMAN/ORA Errors and notify accordingly

RMANERROR=`egrep "ORA-|RMAN-" $RMAN_LOG_TSBKUP`
RMANWARN=`egrep "ORA-|RMAN-" $RMAN_LOG_TSBKUP|egrep -vE "$EGREP_EXCLUDE"`


if [ -z "$RMANERROR" ]
then
   echo "No Errors"
   cat $RMAN_LOG_TSBKUP |mailx -s "SUCCESS - DW_TS_BACKUP Complete" `cat $EMAIL_SUCCESS_DIST`
elif [ -z "$RMANWARN" ]
then
   echo "No Errors, but Warnings"
   cat $RMAN_LOG_TSBKUP |mailx -s "SUCCESS (with ignorable WARNINGS) - DW_TS_BACKUP Complete" `cat $EMAIL_SUCCESS_DIST`
else
   echo "Errors Found !!!!"
   mailx -s "FAILURE - DW_TS_BACKUP Complete" `cat $EMAIL_FAIL_DIST`
fi
}
```

Comment: What isn't working with this?

Comment: When dumping the contents of a file into an email I'd generally do this: `(cmd1; cmd2; cmd3) | mailx -s "subject"`

Comment: File too big for the exchange server, the limit is 10mg and the file is 14mg

Comment: Correct, I understood that, but if you run any commands that require being sent via email the pattern of collecting the output and piping it into mailx as I described is generally what you'll see other's doing.

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at shell scripting. so, if I need to have ORA- and RMAN- extracted out of the log file(RMAN_LOG_TSBKUP) and have that part of the e-mail content, how would I do incorporate in the above e-mail script?

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options:

1 - Instead of `cat`ing the entire log file into the email, you can include only newly appended lines using `tail -n x $RMAN_LOG_TSBKUP` instead of `cat $RMAN_LOG_TSBKUP` where x is the number of lines from the end of the file to include in the email.  If you know roughly about how many lines the backup will add to the log then you can refine x and avoid including old log data.  Or you can `grep` for a log header or date, it's up to you.

2 - Implement log versioning with `logrotate`.  Create a basic config file and drop it in `/etc/logrotate.d/` and `logrotate` will take care of everything for you.  You can configure logs to be rotated based on a schedule or by size.  `logrotate` is typically ran as a daily cronjob from `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`.  This is probably the best option as it will allow you to save logs in a manageable way.  A basic config could include the directives below.

```
 /var/log/oracle-backup.log {
  size 1M
  rotate 12
  monthly
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

The directives are pretty self explanatory but `man logrotate` has good information and here's a good link [How To Manage Log Files With Logrotate On Ubuntu 12.10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: Option:1 the errors are not at the end of the file, it would through out file, so tail would not give me any useful information. I need to grep(somehow) lines that starts with ORA- and RMAN-

Comment: Option:2 would be good for a log where lines will be appended. in our case, these backup logs or new each times with the date and time.

Comment: @Ram so each backup generates a 14 MB log file?

Comment: yes. this is for a 80TB database size and it generate lots of information.

Comment: @Ram I think your best best will be to decide what information you really need from the logs and `grep` for it like you said or rework the backup/logging routine to create smaller logs